# Importing React as default module not working inside Symfony Webpack Encore project

Tags: reactjs, symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I have a Symfony project, where the frontend-pipeline is built with [Webpack Encore](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore), I would like to add React to the project and have a React widget inserted into one of my server-side rendered pages.

I've followed [the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/reactjs.html) and extended my `webpack.config.js` with the following one-liner `.enableReactPreset()`. I'm also writting my JS in TypeScript (I already have some non-react based JS in the project that's compiled from TS, thus I'm writing my react components in `.tsx` files).

I create an entrypoint for my react widget that looks like this

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./map.scss";
import App from "./components/App";

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("map-app")
);
```

When I start the app in watch mode with `encore dev` I don't see any errors in my console and the code compiles, but when I check the output in my browser I get an error, telling me that it `can not read property render of undefined`.

I've logged out `React` and `ReactDOM` and they both show to be `undefined`.
The strange thing is that my editor (PHPStrom) sees the imported module pointing to the respective `index.d.ts` files of these packages and intellisense works on them (I get the `render` method autocompleted for instance).

I've enabled `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` in my project's `tsconfig.json`.

Now I could solve the problem with a workaround. If I import these libraries like so:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

console.log(React); // no longer undefined, I get an object with all of react's methods
```

It works, but it's a bit awkward, and also this way I can't import the named components from react.
For instance this also fails:

```js
import {useState} from "react";

console.log(useState); // undefined
```

I can only make it work like so:

```js
import * as React from "react";

console.log(React.useState); // I get the function
```

I would like to understand why is this happening and how to make the default exports work properly like in all other React projects.

My `package.json` currently looks like this:

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^1.7.*",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.33",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.5.5",
    "@types/leaflet.markercluster": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.6.1",
    "core-js": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.3.0",
    "sass-loader": "^12.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.4",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/Cooty/the-bedechka-case"
  },
  "name": "the-bedechka-case-website-frontend",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
    "dev": "encore dev",
    "watch": "encore dev --watch",
    "build": "encore production --progress"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "defaults"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "fg-loadcss": "^2.1.0",
    "html5sortable": "^0.10.0",
    "jquery": "3.5",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "leaflet.markercluster": "^1.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-leaflet": "^3.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1"
  }
}
```

This is my current `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "vendor",
    "var",
    "translations",
    "tests",
    "src",
    "public",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

and my `webpack.config.js`

```js
const Encore = require("@symfony/webpack-encore");

const babelLoader = {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: "babel-loader",
    options: {
        presets: [
            [
                "@babel/preset-env",
                {
                    "useBuiltIns": "entry",
                    "corejs": {version: 3, proposals: true}
                },
            ]
        ]
    }
};

Encore
    .setOutputPath("public/build/")
    .copyFiles({
        from: "./assets/images",
        to: "images/[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]"
    })
    .setPublicPath("/build")
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .enableSourceMaps()
    .enableReactPreset()
    .addEntry("app", "./templates/ts/app.ts")
    .addEntry("home", "./templates/home/home.ts")
    .addEntry("map", "./templates/map/map.tsx")
    .addEntry("yt", "./templates/components/youtube-embed/youtube-embed.ts")
    .addEntry("admin", "./templates/admin/ts/admin.ts")
    .addStyleEntry("the-crew", "./templates/the-crew/the-crew.scss")
    .addStyleEntry("protagonists", "./templates/protagonists/protagonists.scss")
    .addStyleEntry("screenings", "./templates/screenings/screenings.scss")
    .addStyleEntry("partners", "./templates/partners/partners.scss")
    .addStyleEntry("critical-path", "./templates/scss/critical-path.scss")
    .addStyleEntry("critical-path-home", "./templates/home/critical-path-home.scss")
    .addStyleEntry("critical-path-subpages", "./templates/scss/critical-path-subpages.scss")
    .enableTypeScriptLoader()
    .enableForkedTypeScriptTypesChecking()
    .addLoader(babelLoader)
    .enablePostCssLoader()
    .enableSassLoader()
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .splitEntryChunks();

const config = Encore.getWebpackConfig();

config.optimization.noEmitOnErrors = true;

module.exports = config;
```

You can also checkout the branch where this feature is being implemented [here](https://github.com/Cooty/the-bedechka-case/tree/feature/add-stand-alone-map-page).

Answer (score 0):

In our case we have in compiler options `"esModuleInterop": true`, so we have something like this:

```json
{
    "ecmaVersion": 2021,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "include": [
        "assets/js/**/*.ts",
        "assets/js/**/*.tsx",
        "assets/js/**/*.js",
        "assets/js/**/*.jsx",
        "templates/**/*.ts",
        "templates/**/*.tsx",
        "templates/**/*.js",
        "templates/**/*.jsx"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "public",
        "vendor"
    ]
}
```

We have a more complex webpackconfig be we use the same options regarding React:

```js
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
const path = require('path');
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin');
const StyleLintPlugin = require('stylelint-webpack-plugin');
const {
    bundlesScssPath,
    bundlesJsPath,
    templatesPath
} = require('./webpack/configs/utils.config');
const vendorsAddEntries = require('./webpack/configs/vendors-add-entries.config');
const projectAddEntries = require('./webpack/configs/project-add-entries.config');
const coreVendorsAddEntries = require('./webpack/configs/core-vendors-add-entries.config');
const designStoryAddEntries = require('./webpack/configs/design-story-add-entries.config');
const cssAddEntries = require('./webpack/configs/css-add-entries.config');

vendorsAddEntries();
coreVendorsAddEntries();
projectAddEntries();
designStoryAddEntries();
cssAddEntries();

// +-------------+
// | Main config |
// +-------------+
// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
     * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.scss) if you JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    // +-------------------+
    // | common js entries |
    // +-------------------+
    // .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.ts')
    .addEntry('vendors', path.resolve('./' + path.join(bundlesJsPath, 'vendors/index.ts')))
    .addEntry('components', path.resolve('./' + path.join(templatesPath, 'DesignStory/components/components.ts')))

    // +---------------+
    // | configuration |
    // +---------------+
    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css) and assets cache issues on production
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabel(() => {}, {
        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
        corejs: 3
    })
    // +------------+
    // | TS + React |
    // +------------+
    // uncomment if you use API Platform Admin (composer req api-admin)
    .enableReactPreset()
    .enableTypeScriptLoader((tsConfig) => {
        // You can use this callback function to adjust ts-loader settings
        // https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/blob/master/README.md#loader-options
        // For example:
        // tsConfig.silent = false
    })
    // optionally enable forked type script for faster builds
    // https://www.npmjs.com/package/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
    // requires that you have a tsconfig.json file that is setup correctly.
    .enableForkedTypeScriptTypesChecking(options => {
        delete options.parser;
    })
    .addPlugin(new ESLintPlugin({
        extensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
        exclude: [
            'node_modules',
            'vendor'
        ],
    }))
    .addPlugin(new StyleLintPlugin({
        context: path.resolve(__dirname),
        configFile: '.stylelintrc.json',
        files: [
            path.join(bundlesScssPath, '**/*.s+(a|c)ss'),
            path.join(templatesPath, '**/*.s+(a|c)ss')
        ]
    }))

    // +-----------------+
    // | SASS/postprefix |
    // +-----------------+
    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    .enableSassLoader((options) => {
            // add or set custom options
            // options.includePaths: ["absolute/path/a", "absolute/path/b"];
            // options.warnRuleAsWarning = true;
        }, {}
    )
    // Convert fonts to base64 inline (avoid font loading issue on pdf to html generation with wkhtml2pdf)
    .addLoader({
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
        use: ['base64-inline-loader'],
        type: 'javascript/auto',
    })
    // enable autoprefixing for css
    .enablePostCssLoader((options) => {
        options.postcssOptions = {
            // the directory where the postcss.config.js file is stored
            config: path.resolve(__dirname, 'postcss.config.js')
        };
    })

    // uncomment to get integrity="..." attributes on your script & link tags
    // requires WebpackEncoreBundle 1.4 or higher
    //.enableIntegrityHashes()
    .addExternals(
        {
            'bazinga-translator': 'Translator'
        }
    )
    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    .autoProvidejQuery()
    // you can use this method to provide other common global variables,
    // such as '_' for the 'underscore' library
    // .autoProvideVariables({
    //     $: 'jquery',
    //     jQuery: 'jquery',
    //     'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    // })

    .copyFiles({
        from: './assets/images',
        to: 'images/[path][name].[ext]',
        pattern: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|ico|gif)$/
    })

    // +-------------+
    // | performance |
    // +-------------+
    // A simple technique to improve the performance of web applications is to reduce
    // the number of HTTP requests inlining small files as base64 encoded URLs in the
    // generated CSS files.
    .configureImageRule({
        // tell Webpack it should consider inlining
        type: 'asset',
        //maxSize: 4 * 1024, // 4 kb - the default is 8kb
    })
    // same here
    .configureFontRule({
        type: 'asset',
        //maxSize: 4 * 1024
    })
;

if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Hopes it will help